# Cursor jumps to the end of the input line while try to enter the value in between

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have done this code for not allowing space at the first position and special characters in the input field. This is working fine now. But cursor is moving to the end while trying to type at the first position or middle.Because I'm assigning str to e.target.value. this is happening only in safari browser.
This is my code.

```
var inputValue = e.target.value; // get input value
let str = inputValue;
str = str.replace(/^\s+/, '');    
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, ""); 
e.target.value = str;
```

Can anyone tell me a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var inputValue = e.target.value; // get input value
document.getElementById("yourInputId").value = inputValue.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, "");
```